# Change data-zoom HTML in Img

Tags: javascript, html

Please Copy and paste this code and try. Because I can't change when select a photo in the photo bigger.
for example when I choose a img this should be placed in the bigger one so I need this because I waste much time trying this. This code has functionality of show details of products in a ecommerce. But I want that function in my web page.

```
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>eCommerce Product Detail</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>

/*****************globals*************/
body {
  font-family: 'open sans';
  overflow-x: hidden; }

img {
  max-width: 100%; }

.preview {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column; }
  @media screen and (max-width: 996px) {
    .preview {
      margin-bottom: 20px; } }

.preview-pic {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1; }

.preview-thumbnail.nav-tabs {
  border: none;
  margin-top: 15px; }
  .preview-thumbnail.nav-tabs li {
    width: 18%;
    margin-right: 2.5%; }
    .preview-thumbnail.nav-tabs li img {
      max-width: 100%;
      display: block; }
    .preview-thumbnail.nav-tabs li a {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0; }
    .preview-thumbnail.nav-tabs li:last-of-type {
      margin-right: 0; }

.tab-content {
  overflow: hidden; }
  .tab-content img {
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-animation-name: opacity;
            animation-name: opacity;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .3s;
            animation-duration: .3s; }

.card {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 3em;
  line-height: 1.5em; }

@media screen and (min-width: 997px) {
  .wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex; } }

.details {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column; }

.active{
border:#000 3px solid;
}

.colors {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1; }

.product-title, .price, .sizes, .colors {
  text-transform: UPPERCASE;
  font-weight: bold; }

.checked, .price span {
  color: #ff9f1a; }

.product-title, .rating, .product-description, .price, .vote, .sizes {
  margin-bottom: 15px; }

.product-title {
  margin-top: 0; }

.size {
  margin-right: 10px; }
  .size:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 40px; }

.color {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 10px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  border-radius: 2px; }
  .color:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 20px; }

.add-to-cart, .like {
  background: #ff9f1a;
  padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
  border: none;
  text-transform: UPPERCASE;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: background .3s ease;
          transition: background .3s ease; }
  .add-to-cart:hover, .like:hover {
    background: #b36800;
    color: #fff; }

.not-available {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em; }
  .not-available:before {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    content: "\f00d";
    color: #fff; }

.orange {
  background: #ff9f1a; }

.green {
  background: #85ad00; }

.blue {
  background: #0076ad; }

.tooltip-inner {
  padding: 1.3em; }

@-webkit-keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
            transform: scale(3); }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

@keyframes opacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
            transform: scale(3); }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1); } }

/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="container-fliud">
                <div class="wrapper row">
                    <div class="preview col-md-6">
                        <div class=" tab-content">
                          <div class="tab-pane active" ><img id="pic-1" src="http://placekitten.com/400/252" /></div>
                          <div id="imgtext"></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="preview-thumbnail nav nav-tabs">
                          <li >
                              <a>
                                <img  class="active" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature.jpg" alt="Nature" style="width:100%"
                                onclick="myFunction(this);">

                          </a></li>
                          <li><a >   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%"
                            onclick="myFunction(this);"></a></li>
                          <li><a > <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%"
                            onclick="myFunction(this);"></a></li>
                          <li><a > <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%"
                            onclick="myFunction(this);"></a></li>
                            <li><a > <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_lights.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%"
                                onclick="myFunction(this);"></a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="details col-md-6">
                        <h3 class="product-title">men's shoes fashion</h3>
                        <div class="rating">
                            <div class="stars">
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="review-no">41 reviews</span>
                        </div>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>
                        <p class="product-description">Suspendisse quos? Tempus cras iure temporibus? Eu laudantium cubilia sem sem! Repudiandae et! Massa senectus enim minim sociosqu delectus posuere.</p>


                        <h4 class="price">current price: <span>$180</span></h4>
                        <p class="vote"><strong>91%</strong> of buyers enjoyed this product! <strong>(87 votes)</strong></p>
                        <h5 class="sizes">sizes:
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="small">s</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="medium">m</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="large">l</span>
                            <span class="size" data-toggle="tooltip" title="xtra large">xl</span>
                        </h5>
                        <h5 class="colors">colors:
                            <span class="color orange not-available" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Not In store"></span>
                            <span class="color green"></span>
                            <span class="color blue"></span>
                        </h5>
                        <div class="action">
                            <button class="add-to-cart btn btn-default" type="button">add to cart</button>
                            <button class="like btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="fa fa-heart"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/igorlino/elevatezoom-plus/1.1.6/src/jquery.ez-plus.js"></script>

<script>

$('#pic-1').ezPlus({
zoomType                : "lens",
lensShape : "round",
lensSize    : 200
});
   function myFunction(imgs) {
      var expandImg = document.getElementById("pic-1");
      var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");

      $( '.preview-thumbnail' ).find( 'img.active' ).removeClass( 'active' );


    imgs.className += "active";

          expandImg.src = imgs.src+"?w=400&amp;ch=DPR&amp;dpr=2";
          imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
          expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";

     }

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the function:

```
$("#pic-1").data('zoom-image', imgs.src+"?w=1200&amp;ch=DPR&amp;dpr=2").ezPlus({
                  zoomType: "lens",
                  lensShape : "round",
                  lensSize: 200
            });
```